# how to get 1st column value with 30 minutes rule and sessionize the activity data

Tags: sql, postgresql, rank, gaps-and-islands

I have an activity table called myTable, the data looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    userid      text,
    webid         text,
    "ts" timestamp
);

INSERT INTO myTable
    ("userid", "webid", "ts")
VALUES ('A', '34', '2023-01-31 16:34:49.000'),
       ('A', '97', '2023-01-31 16:34:58.000'),
       ('A', '17', '2023-01-31 17:35:02.000'),
       ('A', '17', '2023-01-31 17:35:07.000'),
       ('A', '17', '2023-01-31 17:35:18.000'),
       ('A', '1', '2023-01-31 17:35:37.000'),
       ('A', '1', '2023-01-31 17:35:38.000'),
       ('A', '77', '2023-01-31 17:35:41.000'),
       ('A', '77', '2023-01-31 17:35:42.000'),
       ('A', '1', '2023-01-31 17:37:10.000'),
       ('A', '1', '2023-01-31 17:37:12.000'),
       ('A', '77', '2023-01-31 17:37:14.000'),
       ('A', '77', '2023-01-31 17:52:14.000'),
       ('A', '77', '2023-01-31 18:12:14.000'),
       ('A', '77', '2023-01-31 18:45:14.000'),
       ('A', '77', '2023-01-31 18:55:15.000'),
       ('B', '33', '2023-01-31 06:37:15.000'),
       ('B', '56', '2023-01-31 06:40:15.000')
  ;
```

| userid | webid | ts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 34 | 2023-01-31 16:34:49 |
| A | 97 | 2023-01-31 17:34:58 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:07 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:18 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:35:37 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:35:38 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:35:41 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:35:42 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:37:10 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:37:12 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:37:14 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:52:14 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 18:12:14 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 18:45:14 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 18:55:15 |
| B | 33 | 2023-01-31 06:37:15 |
| B | 56 | 2023-01-31 06:40:15 |

The output I want to return as following:

| userid | webid | ts | first_ts | session_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 34 | 2023-01-31 16:34:49 | 2023-01-31 16:34:49 | 1 |
| A | 97 | 2023-01-31 17:34:58 | 2023-01-31 17:34:58 | 2 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 | 3 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:07 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 | 3 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:18 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 | 3 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:35:37 | 2023-01-31 17:35:37 | 4 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:35:38 | 2023-01-31 17:35:37 | 4 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:35:41 | 2023-01-31 17:35:41 | 5 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:35:42 | 2023-01-31 17:35:41 | 5 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:37:10 | 2023-01-31 17:37:10 | 6 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:37:12 | 2023-01-31 17:37:10 | 6 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:37:14 | 2023-01-31 17:37:14 | 7 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:40:14 | 2023-01-31 17:52:14 | 7 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 18:15:14 | 2023-01-31 18:12:14 | 7 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 18:37:15 | 2023-01-31 18:45:14 | 8 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 18:37:15 | 2023-01-31 18:55:15 | 8 |
| B | 33 | 2023-01-31 06:37:15 | 2023-01-31 06:37:15 | 1 |
| B | 56 | 2023-01-31 06:40:15 | 2023-01-31 06:40:15 | 2 |

first_ts means first timestamp. The logic for first_ts is
If a userid visits same webid at consecutive timestamp and each timestamp's interval falls within 30 minutes, these will be recorded as a session. For example, row 3, 4, and 5. Each time interval are less than 30 minutes, their first_ts is the timestamp of the first event, which is 2023-01-31 17:35:02.

If a userid visits a webid and jump to another webid and return back to the first webid, the first_ts will be refreshed to current timestamp. For example, row 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11. userid A visits webid=1 at first, but jump to webid=77, after return back to webid=1, then row 10 and row 11 should be recorded as a new session with new first_ts.

If a userid visits a webid at consecutive timestamps, and one timestamp interval is greater than 30 minutes, it will also break the session and the first_ts will be refreshed as well. For example, row 12, 13, 14, 15, 16. Between row 14 and row 15, their time interval are 33 minutes (>30), so for row 15 and row 16, their first_ts refreshed to current timestamp and they are to be a new session.

I share my script here, the script haven't included the session_id because I found out it doesn't return correct first_ts for me to do the dense_rank on session_id.
extract(epoch()) function is same as datediff() function in sql. Since I am testing the data using Postgresql, it doesn't have datediff() function. so I use exract(epoch()) to calculate time difference.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY ts) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid, webid ORDER BY ts) rn2
    FROM myTable
)

SELECT userid, webid, ts,
       lag(ts,1) over(partition by userid order by ts) as previous_ts,
       case when extract(epoch from (ts - lag(ts,1) over(partition by userid order by ts asc))) <= 1800 then MIN(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY userid, webid, rn1 - rn2) 
            when extract(epoch from (ts - lag(ts,1) over(partition by userid order by ts asc))) > 1800 then ts
            when lag(ts,1) over(partition by userid order by ts) is NULL then ts
       end as first_ts
FROM cte
ORDER BY userid, ts;
```

Anyone has a better solution to do the task? Thanks!

script reference: https://dbfiddle.uk/SL7EtQSy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reads like a gaps-and-islands problem, where islands are consecutive rows that belong to the same user and webid with a lesser gap than 30 minutes.

Here is one way to do it:

```
select t.*, min(ts) over(partition by userid, session_id order by ts) first_ts
from (
    select t.*,
        1 + count(*) 
            filter(where webid != lag_webid or ts > lag_ts + interval '30' minute) 
            over(partition by userid order by ts) session_id
    from (
        select t.*, 
            lag(webid, 1, webid) over(partition by userid order by ts) lag_webid,
            lag(ts, 1, ts)       over(partition by userid order by ts) lag_ts
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
```

The most inner subquery retrieves the "last" webid and timestamp for each user. With this information at hand, we can identify each group of records with a conditional count of gaps (column `session_id`). The last step is to recover the first timestamp of each island, that is `first_ts`.

In **[your DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HO83KYVx)**, this produces:

| userid | webid | ts | lag_webid | lag_ts | session_id | first_ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 34 | 2023-01-31 16:34:49 | 34 | 2023-01-31 16:34:49 | 1 | 2023-01-31 16:34:49 |
| A | 97 | 2023-01-31 16:34:58 | 34 | 2023-01-31 16:34:49 | 2 | 2023-01-31 16:34:58 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 | 97 | 2023-01-31 16:34:58 | 3 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:07 | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 | 3 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:18 | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:07 | 3 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:35:37 | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:18 | 4 | 2023-01-31 17:35:37 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:35:38 | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:35:37 | 4 | 2023-01-31 17:35:37 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:35:41 | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:35:38 | 5 | 2023-01-31 17:35:41 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:35:42 | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:35:41 | 5 | 2023-01-31 17:35:41 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:37:10 | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:35:42 | 6 | 2023-01-31 17:37:10 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:37:12 | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:37:10 | 6 | 2023-01-31 17:37:10 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:37:14 | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:37:12 | 7 | 2023-01-31 17:37:14 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:52:14 | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:37:14 | 7 | 2023-01-31 17:37:14 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 18:12:14 | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:52:14 | 7 | 2023-01-31 17:37:14 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 18:45:14 | 77 | 2023-01-31 18:12:14 | 8 | 2023-01-31 18:45:14 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 18:55:15 | 77 | 2023-01-31 18:45:14 | 8 | 2023-01-31 18:45:14 |
| B | 33 | 2023-01-31 06:37:15 | 33 | 2023-01-31 06:37:15 | 1 | 2023-01-31 06:37:15 |
| B | 56 | 2023-01-31 06:40:15 | 33 | 2023-01-31 06:37:15 | 2 | 2023-01-31 06:40:15 |

Side note: the conditional count is somehow Postgres specific (few databases support the `filter` clause to aggregate/window functions). A more generic expression would be to replace this:

```
count(*) 
    filter(where webid != lag_webid or ts > lag_ts + interval '30' minute) 
    over(partition by userid order by ts) session_id
```

With:

```
sum(case when webid != lag_webid or ts > lag_ts + interval '30' minute then 1 else 0 end) 
    over(partition by userid order by ts) session_id
```

Comment: I change it to "sum(case when webid != lag_webid or datediff(minutes, ts,lag_ts) > 30 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by userid order by ts)+1 session_id", and it's till 1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,1,2. do you know why?

Comment: i figure out. it's a little tricky, after i switch to datediff(minutes, lag_ts, ts) > 30, it's correct. Thanks a lot!